# What exactly am I doing wrong here? Trying to fill and ArrayCollection with an Object

Tags: actionscript

```
public function capturaPermisos():ArrayCollection{
                var arrayColl:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
                for(var i:int=0; i < dataProvider.length; i++){
                    object.idModulo = dataProvider[i].idModulo;
                    object.consultar = dataProvider[i].consultar;
                    object.agregar = dataProvider[i].agregar;
                    object.modificar = dataProvider[i].modificar;
                    object.eliminar = dataProvider[i].eliminar;
                    arrayColl[i].addItem(object);
                }
                return arrayColl;
            }
```

dataProvider comes  from a datagrid, hence the cycle. The object is declared globally outside the funcion.

```
for each(var per:Object in adgPermisos.dataProvider)
                {
                    permiso.idModulo = per.idModulo;
                    permiso.consultar = per.consultar;
                    permiso.agregar = per.agregar;
                    permiso.modificar = per.modificar;
                    permiso.eliminar = per.eliminar;
                    permisos.addItem(permiso);
                }
```

The second loop does exactly the same wrong result.

It saves the last registry of my dataprovider in all 3 lines of the arraycollection (the dataprovider.length is 3)

My dataProvider is an arrayCollection too, but it is not the same Arrcooll that fills my Datagrid. When I want to send my data to server there are diferent values added from checkboxes inside my datagrid and renders the arrayCollection different than it was when the datagrid was filled.

I just want to fill another arrayCollection to send it to my java webservice like this;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It saves the last registry of my dataprovider in all 3 lines of the arraycollection": you are probably referencing the same object [permiso] in the loop 3 times.  As a result you add this same object 3 times, and you change this same object again 3 times. (As a result, all 3 entries in your permisos contain the same object permiso which has been changed 3 times). Try the following code to solve the issue:

```
         for each(var per:Object in adgPermisos.dataProvider)
            {
                var newItem : Object = ObjectUtil.clone(permiso);
                newItem.idModulo = per.idModulo;
                newItem.consultar = per.consultar;
                newItem.agregar = per.agregar;
                newItem.modificar = per.modificar;
                newItem.eliminar = per.eliminar;
                permisos.addItem(newItem);
            }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the object is declared outside the function. Oh and the dataprovider.length was a translation mistake, I forgot to paste that one.

Comment: Do you add the same object multiple times? You should also probably change **arrayColl[i].addItem(object);** to **arrayColl.addItem(object);**. Another thing you might consider is instead of cloning objects from dataProvider, you could set it [dataProvider] directly to the arrayColl. (For example if dataProvider is of type Array, you could set it as **arrayColl.source = dataProvider;**)

Comment: Please see my original question.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean by "My dataProvider is an arrayCollection too, but it is not the same Arrcooll that fills my Datagrid." If you have some DataGrid, and some ArrayCollection referencing 3 items, and you set this ArrayCollection as a dataProvider of your DataGrid, then this DataGrid would be referencing these same 3 items, and if you do any changes from the DataGrid to these items, they will get changed in your original ArrayCollection.